# Errtrace and local

Tags: bash, function, error-handling, trap

I am using the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -Eu

trap 'echo Hi' ERR

exit_failure() {
  echo "Hello, World!"
  return 1
}

sub_failure() {
  res=$(exit_failure)
}

sub_failure
```

It results in the following:

```
Hi
Hi
```

If I change `sub_failure()` to the following, however:

```sh
sub_failure() {
  local res=$(exit_failure)
}
```

I get no output; `ERR` is not trapped anymore? Why is the signal hidden? How can I trap `ERR` if I want to use local variables? I know I can do `local res; res=$(exit_failure)`, but why do I have to separate both?

Comment: `local` is almost definitely the problem - it's not exactly a standardized feature - the shell will have its own trick at implementation, which might have unintended or non-standard side effects. It's just the risk you run, I guess. Anyway, the point of `local` is to *not* report to the parent, so, I guess it's just doing it's job really well.

Comment: So the answer is that local does not report to the parent, ok. So generally speaking good style would be to always separate declaration from assignment, right?

Comment: It's a shell-script - *good style* is an incredibly relative term. Probably *good style* doesn't blow up. Still, if I ever use it I do it with declarations. *Better style* is to not declare variables in current shell functions - use your positional array to the utmost. Do `man set`.

Comment: man set does not work. Positional array, why? I just want to decrease the visibility nothing more...

Comment: `man set` does not work? Wow. Anyway, it was the wrong advice. I think you want to look at `return` - just use `$?`.

Comment: `local foo=$(bar)` passes the expanded results of `foo=$(bar)` as arguments (oh yes, you should use `local "foo=$(bar)"` or you will get word splitting), and probably command substitution in assignment and commands are handled differently (sounds like a bug, hmm). Probably you should ask `bug-bash`.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a bug. It's actually defined behavior.

When using `bash -Eux` you can see what happens. (`-Eu` from your shebang + `-x`)

```
+ trap 'echo Hi' ERR
+ sub_failure
++ exit_failure
++ echo 'Hello, World!'
++ return 1
+++ echo Hi
+ res='Hello, World!
Hi'
++ echo Hi
Hi
++ echo Hi
Hi
```

When doing command substitution the `trap` is inherited because of the `-E` switch. So the "Hi" from the inherited trap triggered by the `return 1` of your `exit_failure()` function becomes part of the value stored in `ret`.
(This is also the case when executing the variant using `local`)

In Addition the `res=...` expression returns `1` (error) and triggers your trap (inside your `sub_failure()` function).

Since `res=...` return `1` and the result of a function is the result of the last command in the function the result of `sub_failure()` is also `1` (error) and your trap is triggered again after `sub_failure` has been executed in the main shell. So you get 2 visible "Hi"s: one for `res=....` and one for `sub_failure` and a hidden "Hi" stored in `$res`.

Now for the `local` variant:

```
+ trap 'echo Hi' ERR
+ sub_failure
++ exit_failure
++ echo 'Hello, World!'
++ return 1
+++ echo Hi
+ local 'res=Hello, World!
Hi'
```

By definition `local` always returns `0` when used in a function. Causing your `local res=...` to evaluate to `0` (success) while still having the hidden "Hi" stored in `$res`. And since `res=..` evaluates to `0` `sub_failure` also returns `0`. So this time you get one "hidden" fail and two time success.

Hope this helps even if this thread is quiet old ;)

And it should also be clear why splitting `local res=...` in

```
local res
res=....
```

does restore the behavior of the first variant.. ? ;)

Comment: +1 even if this thread is old, great analysis

Comment: +100 "even if this thread is old, great analysis" :)
the final workaround should be put in bold, it's a very tricky case, and not so easy to google ! (and the workaround works, obviously)